# BitmapFactory.decodeFile returns "" for valid file path

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have an image that is saved in this place

```
/data/user/0/com.package.name/files/3_20200302_1915403011639805937138468.jpg
```

I want to load it in a bitmap as below

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath)
```

Even though the image exists and when the debugger stops in that point i can see the BitMap (debugers button that allows to see it) i get this as a result

```
bitmap = ""
```

Don t know why that happens.
Is there a problem that the correct path is data/data and not data/user even though i save it in context.filesDir?

Comment: It will return a valid bitmap. Or null. Not "". So please log its value and tell us please.

Comment: Well finally my mistake was something stupid. I apologize for the inconvienience. Thank you